# Nuget - Writing tools for Package Manager Console (custom cmdlets)

Tags: visual-studio, console, nuget, nuget-package

I've installed nuget package manager and I really love mvc-scaffold extension. I would like to write similar tool for my projects.

Is there any API reference or some documentation for nuget I can learn from ? TIA for any suggestions.

Edit:
Question is already 'answered' (thx one more time), here are some links that can be helpful:

- http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/59864 - package explorer (download + see what it's inside the package - thank God for comments in mvc scaffolding ps scripts :))
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Steve-Sanderson-MvcScaffolding - video from mvcConf2
- and of course Steve Sanderson's blog : http://blog.stevensanderson.com/

Comment: What kind of things are you looking for, general helper APIs?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I wrote the current version of MvcScaffolding that you mention in your question. Here's how it adds PowerShell cmdlets to the Package Manager Console:

- Cmdlets are written in C# and compiled into a .NET assembly (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163293.aspx)
- The .NET assembly is included in MvcScaffolding's "tools" folder (see http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#From_a_convention_based_working_directory)
- MvcScaffolding also contains an init.ps1 file that NuGet runs each time you open a solution containing it (also described at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal). This script uses the PowerShell "Import-Module" command to import the cmdlets from the .NET assembly, making them available in the console.

Note that it's not actually necessary to write your cmdlets in C# and call Import-Module. A simpler alternative is to write them in PowerShell (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff677563.aspx) and define them inline in your NuGet package's init.ps1 file.

Or, if your question is about how to add custom scaffolders to MvcScaffolding (e.g., so you can say "Scaffold MyCustomThing -somecustomparams"), then use the command "Scaffold CustomScaffolder MyCustomThing", and then edit the PS1/T4 files that appear in your CodeTemplates/Scaffolders folder. I'll blog more details about this soon.

Comment: THX!Your third point was something that I was looking for ! :> There are no docs about it. I think it's a really great feature (I want to scaffold some Windows Forms controls at work (to replace shitty templates), and distribute package to another developers to promote nuGet :)). Great job with MvcScaffolding, I like RoR :))

Comment: Also have a look at @steven-sanderson great feature rich presentation at mix 11: [Scaffolding – ASP.NET, NuGet, Entity Framework Code First and More](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM13)