# Visual Studio add custom command to run in Package Manager Console?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to create a button which will automatically run few powershell commands which are imported in nuget package (tools in nuget package)

I found out how to add custom button in this question: [How can I add a custom command to Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414788/how-can-i-add-a-custom-command-to-visual-studio). But I cannot find out how to run from this command in package manager console.

So is there a way to add custom command button to visual studio, which will start and run command in package manager console?

Comment: Is this question related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077711/nuget-writing-tools-for-package-manager-console-custom-cmdlets

Comment: Somehow yes it is, but it only shows how to create custom commands/functions inside package manage console

Answer (score 3):

Using a custom command described by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414788/how-can-i-add-a-custom-command-to-visual-studio), you can run only **external** tools. In your case, you can run NuGet command line utility. First, you need to [download](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget) nuget.exe. Then you have to add a custom command, arguments for it and initial directory in External Tools dialog. You can use solution variables (e.g., $(ProjectFileName), $(SolutionDir)) for arguments and initial directory fields. You can use bat file to run few commands.

Unfortunately, the NuGet command line utility has fewer features than package manager console. I don't know, is it enough of these features to solve your issue?

To use all features of NuGet and to integrate into Visual Studio, you can implement your [VSPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc138589.aspx). From VSPackage you can add at any place of Visual Studio the custom command (as a button or menu item). When the command launch (user clicked your button), you can call any method of [NuGet API](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/invoking-nuget-services-from-inside-visual-studio) inside Visual Studio. This way requires time to develop and not so simple.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to run custom commands in Package Manager Console. They are even not nuget commands but they import and allow to use custom cmdlets