# Does EF6 Code First with enabled Migrations support remote Configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, configuration-files, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

So far in all our web app project(mvc4) db ConnectionString was not in project .config file but on a different server(configuration server) and the application itself pulled it when starting.

Now we are using EF 6 CodeFirst with enabled Migrations.
So when we make changes to db model, in package manage we run:

```
add-migration 'AnotherScript'
```

and then

```
update-database
```

However for this to work ConnectionString needs to be in Web.config so that package manager can find it.

Is there any way to have this connection string remote, and if so how?
The idea is to have package manager run code in my object called ConfigurationUtil that will get remote config.

Comment: Check out [this question's second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327409/how-to-explicitly-name-the-database-when-using-entity-framework-migrations-4-3) - you can pass connection string as `-ConnectionString` parameter of `update-database` - it is not exactly what you want, but may be it is good enough

Answer (score 1):

There IS a solution, but it is not out of the box.

1. You need to implement a custom `Package Manager Console` command that initializes some variable `$connection string` with the connection string from your source. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077711/nuget-writing-tools-for-package-manager-console-custom-cmdlets) for some details.
2. Now you can run `update-database` with custom connection string     `Update-Database -Verbose -ConnectionString $connectionstring`

Comment: Thanks for directions.
But before I start investigating it further, if I would make Custom Package Manager Console, can it work for production as well.
Because there, migration script are execute automatically on publish, and I do not manually type update-database as I do during development on my local computer.

Comment: @Boris if you don't want to run the script ´UpdateDatabase´ manually you can create some logic at the Global file in your project so you can run it from there. Check this blog post on how to run migrations scripts using code -> http://tinyurl.com/ogfdm7j